# Windows firewall outgoing rule exception not working

Tags: windows, firewall, windows-firewall, windows-server-2019

I set custom outbound firewall rule on Windows Server 2019 which deny all outgoing traffic to 192.168.2.0/24. The rule is working for all until I set an exception in "Local principal/Exceptions". When I add an account or group there, EVERYBODY has access as if the rule is not existing.

Is this some bug or I didn't understand the concept?

I'm struggling with this for whole day. Thank you

EDIT: this is the fw rule:

```
Name    Group   Profile   Enabled   Action   Override   Program    Local Address      Remote     Address          Protocol   Local Port            Remote Port

test02  All     No        Block     No       Any        Any        92.168.222.0/24    Any        Any              Any        Any        Any        Any        Any        None
```

Comment: Could add in your question the *inbound and outbound* rules by to use **"Export List..."** on the Windows Firewall.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand.

Comment: Run **wf.msc**, go to **Inbound Rules -> Export List ...** and **Inbound Rules -> Export List ...** to save the rules as text file, so you could add they on your question.

Comment: Ok, I added the rule.

Comment: All rules, Inbound and Outbound. Is that possible for you?